# PHP Form/jQuery validate e-mail address - Display bad email addresses

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin to validate a text file that contains many records (including email addresses).

Example: Textfile.txt

```
1)Last Name, First Name, Email Address
..
..
100)Last Name, First Name, Email Address
```

If a bad email address is found, a list of the offending email addresses will be displayed in a textarea before the text file is loaded.

The closeset plugin I've found: http://lifeasrose.ca/2011/01/tutorial-using-jquery-to-validate-form-input/

This only validates a single email form input field. Any advise or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't access files with JavaScript

Comment: There's not enough information here - where is `Textfile.txt`? On the server, the user's local hard disk? Is it a file which the user just uploaded? And what does the 'PHP form' bit in your title mean?

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee yes you can, with HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 to read file contents with Javascript. Demo [here](http://html5demos.com/file-api)

Another nice example [here] http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

> FileReader.readAsText(Blob|File, opt_encoding) - The result property
>   will contain the file/blob's data as a text string. By default the
>   string is decoded as 'UTF-8'. Use the optional encoding parameter can
>   specify a different format.

Comment: You're right, but the only browsers that support this are Chrome Firefox and Opera, it would be much better to read the file with PHP and then do the rest with JavaScript